# member login in angular2 support ticket system

Tags: angular

I am learning angular2. With lots of hardwork and community help, I was able to complete my first angular2 app. It is simple support ticket system.

I made a major mistake in my design, I made entire app without considering the fact that only logged in users can create support ticket.

Now please advise me what is the best method for me to achieve this considering my situation?

**Option 1**: 
I build the angular2 login form, example tutorial is here:
http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/
and here
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

If I go this way, i dont know where i will store the LOGGED IN username so that it is available to all my components throughout the project after successful login and how secure this method will be (because login credentials will be in javascript and passed via json to server)?

**Option 2** :
Second option is that I build the php and static html login form that will reside on the domain root and then after successful login I will redirect to the angular2 app which will reside in /tickets/ folder.

Challenge here is that how will i pass logged in username from php to the angular2 app? index.html in angular2 is static file.

I am stuck no matter which direction i choose

Please help thanks

Comment: Second direction is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the first option. using localStorage to "cache" your login information temporarily is pretty standard. All your components should be able to access localStorage. Just inject whatever service you use to store the data to the components that require the user data. In my opinion, I would say this is an easier route, and can be made as secure as you want it to be. That first link has all you need..

```
  import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
  import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

  export class User {
    constructor(
      public email: string,
      public password: string) { }
  }

  var users = [
    new User('admin@admin.com','adm9'),
    new User('user1@gmail.com','a23')
  ];

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor(
      private _router: Router){}

    logout() {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      this._router.navigate(['Login']);
    }

    login(user){
      var authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.email === user.email);
      if (authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.password === user.password){
        localStorage.setItem("user", authenticatedUser);
        this._router.navigate(['Home']);      
        return true;
      }
      return false;

    }

    checkCredentials(){
      if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null){
          this._router.navigate(['Login']);
      }
    } 
  }
```

Where the users array is what you check the username/passwords with. This can easily be replaced by some http request, or whatever/wherever it is you want to look for all the users. Then in your components, prior to showing anydata, call checkCredentials()

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late. I had some issues and that kept me away from work. I will test and choose your advised path. I will update you on how it goes. Thanks again for your valued time. And once again sorry for writing to you late.